# Optimizing g++ when indexing an array with an injective function

Tags: c++, optimization, compiler-construction, g++

I have a for loop where each step i, it processes an array element p[f(i)], where f(i) is an injective (one-to-one) map from 1...n to 1...m (m > n). So there is no data coupling in the loop and all compiler optimization techniques such as pipelining can be used. But how can I inform g++ of the injectivity of f(i)? Or do I even need to (can g++ figure that out)?

Comment: I'm not sure that there *are* any optimizations to be had here because of the way C++ treats arrays.  However, I'm going to follow this because I'm curious.

Comment: How much happens inside function `f(i)`? If much happens in there, any optimizations outside it will not make much difference. Also, if the body of the `for` loop does much, any optimizations of the loop itself will not make much difference.

Comment: The function f(i) is just changing the index based on global information that does not change inside the loop.  It's just telling the loop which part of a 3d space to iterate over.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that `f` doesn't rely on any global state and produces no side effects, you can tag it with the [`const` attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bconst_007d-function-attribute-2398):

```
int f(int i) __attribute__((const));
```

If `f` does rely on global state but still has the property that it's a pure function of its inputs and global state (and produces no side effects), you can use the the slightly weaker [`pure` attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bpure_007d-function-attribute-2458).

These attributes let gcc make more optimizations than it otherwise could, although I don't know if these will be helpful in your case.  Take a look at the generated assembly code and see if they help.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try processing the loop with a temporary storage array, i.e.:

```
temp[i]= process(p[f(i)]);
```

then copy the results back:

```
p[f(i)]= temp[i];
```

Assuming you declared `p` and `temp` to be restricted pointers, the compiler has enough information to optimize a little more aggressively.

Answer (score 0):

If the definition of f() is in scope and is inlineable most any good compiler should first inline it into the function, then the next optimization passes should be able to rewrite the code as if the function call wasn't there.